# Connect to MySQL from terminal with special characters in password not working

Tags: mysql, quoting

My MySQL password contains **!@#**. When i try to connect to mysql from the terminal using this password, I gives me a *bash event not found* error.[image]
How do i fix this? I don't even understand why this error shows up with the password.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be sure to quote special characters. `!` matches the pattern `!<event ID>` where `<event ID>` is something in your `history`.

Here's my history:

```
[vagrant@localhost files]$ history
1  tail /var/log/httpd/error_log
2  ./tools/runcmd deploy latest
3  ./tools/runcmd deploy fntsy.2625
4  ./tools/runcmd deploy fntsy-2625
```

So when I type `!1` I get:

```
[vagrant@localhost files]$ tail /var/log/httpd/error_log
<!-- tail information here -->
```

In your case, the command line can't find an event with the ID `@#`, because nothing in your history matches that.

Try quoting your password: `-p'<your pass>'` or just omit your password altogether (call `mysql -u <your-name> -p` and it will prompt you to type your password in).

Comment: One more thing: dollar signs are special in certain terminals. We had a system password like this that needed to be entered via a script. Even after quoting `-p'$Texas'` did not work. Had to be entered like so: `-p'\$Texas'`

Comment: That would depend on the shell.  In bash, `$` has meaning inside `"` but not inside `'`, and `\` is the same, so the `\` would be a character literal.